# Why does comparison of Double variables return false?

Tags: java, string, reference

Why do String comparisons return true, whereas Double comparisons return false?

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = "a";
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true

Double d1 = 1D;
Double d2 = 1D;
System.out.println(d1 == d2); // false
```

I have some thoughts on my mind on the matter, but it is always a pleasure to hear from you first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String literals are interned - autoboxed *doubles* aren't. Other autoboxing *can* be guaranteed to use cached objects:

```
Integer i1 = 1;
Integer i2 = 1;
System.out.println(i1 == i2); // true, guaranteed
```

Note that this is only *guaranteed* for values from -128 to 127, but *may* work for larger values as well. See [section 5.1.7 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) for more information.

Note that for strings it really is only because of the interning of String constants:

```
String s1 = new String("a");
String s2 = new String("a");
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // false
```

... whereas for integer boxing, the reuse of the cached values is performed at *execution* time:

```
int x = 10;
x -= 9;
Integer i1 = x;
Integer i2 = 1;
System.out.println(i1 == i2); // true, guaranteed
```

Comment: I presume that's part of the JLS, do you have a reference link? For answer completeness :)

Comment: @jon-skeet I liked the way your answer keeps growing when I hit refresh.

Comment: @ptomil: I edited it just a minute ago to give the reference :)

Comment: @Jon can you tell more about cached objects ? What are they ? String, Integer what other ? their specs ?

Comment: @hilal: In this case, it's just a cache of values for boxing in a certain range, to avoid having to create a new object every time. There's also the matter of the interning of string constants, which is slightly different as that's partly performed at compile-time... the compiler emits a reference to the same constant within the class file even if it's used several times in the class, and then the JVM *also* checks whether that string already has an interned value when it loads the class.